# How to setup a FirebaseCloudMessaging server?

Tags: java, android, server, firebase-cloud-messaging

I did the android client side for FCM, I tested it using FCM console.
Now I need to setup a server which gets the registrationId from client using Http link and also sends push notifications. This is the first time I am setting up a server.

Comment: Is there a particular technology stack that you are interested in going with?  Rails might be a good choice.  You could use the FCM gem, https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm, to help sending the notification to Firebase.  The ActiveAdmin gem, http://activeadmin.info/, could help create a basic interface to send and log pushed notifcation and push tokens.  And then you could create a basic API for you client side to sent the tokens to your server.